# VSTO for the Mac?

Tags: .net, mono, outlook, ms-office, vsto

I have built a custom Outlook toolbar option using VSTO which logs an email in a database. This works fine in Windows. However, I’ve been asked if we can migrate this to the Mac for Entourage which I think is the Mac version of Outlook. Can a VSTO application be ported to the Mac? Is it possible to build custom toolbar options in Entourage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VSTO for Mac...no. This [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsto/thread/fe26644b-83ae-4129-98f0-5842e98b7b30/) is older, but it still applies.

Answer (score 1):

No. VSTO , .NET or VBA solutions do not support the current version of Office for Mac.
Supposedly next version of Office for Mac is getting a x86 version of VBA compiler.

By that time though I imagine alot of existing solutions will have been ported to Applescript, wow, what a mess.