# Adding Outlook Object Library to Excel 2011 for Mac

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-addin, excel-2011

I am trying to move a VBA macro code from Excel 2003 to Excel 2011.

The macro requires sending an Email from Outlook. However, when I went to Tool > References to add the Outlook Object Library, it does not show up in the List box.

How do I go about adding the reference in so i can access Outlook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of my knowledge Office Automation in the MAC world is somehow limited. [Please see this discussion.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324439/vsto-for-the-mac) [Also this one in a Microsoft Forum.](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macoutlook/add-in-development/18c3d331-bd85-470a-b2e3-93bc0fe94bd5?msgId=11f72d76-9fea-4bf4-a3bd-fa481e46efae).

Answer (score 0):

You can add reference by using Browse option. 
You just need to add reference to the file "**MSOUTL.OLB**"
In my system I have it in "*C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\MSOUTL.OLB*" , In your system it could be in different folder.