# VSTO Add-In to Mac Excel

Tags: c#, excel, windows, macos, vsto

I have built an Excel Add-In using `**Visual Studio 2015**`, `VSTO add-in`.
The Program has also a Ribbon.
The add-in is working well in the Windows. But Not in `Mac excel`.

I searched that the VSTO add-in will not Supports to MAC.

So,

> Is there any solution to work the add-in in MAC?

Or

> What technology i need to build for MAC?

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: I think your question is too broad! to have an answer here - please be more specific ;).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VSTO for the Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324439/vsto-for-the-mac)